# R Function with Date Input

Tags: r, function, date, posixct

I am automating an R Markdown for reporting with parameters. Individually all of the lines below work manually, but once I wrap the commands in a function and supply dates to the function argument of "%Y-%m-%d" format, I receive this error:

**The Error:**

`Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

**The Function:**

```r
render_reports <- function(SiteName, DateMin, DateMax){

  parameters <- list(SiteName = SiteName, DateMin = DateMin, DateMax = DateMax)

  # Input and Output Directories
  rmd_dir  <- ""
  rmd_name <- "Quarterly_Reporting_RMD.Rmd"
  rmd_path <- paste(rmd_dir, rmd_name, sep = "/")

  word_dir  <- "./Reports"
  word_name <- sprintf("%s", SiteName)
  word_path <- paste(word_dir, word_name, sep = "/")

# Render the RMarkdown Report
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = rmd_name,
    output_format = word_document(reference_docx = "word-styles-reference.docx"),
    output_file = word_name,
    output_dir = word_dir,
    params = parameters
  )
}
```

I have tried coercing `DateMin` and `DateMax` within the function using various `POSIXct`/`POSIXlt` and `lubridate` commands but still result in the same error. Perhaps my understanding of functions is the issue, but it seems to be where the issue resides.

Within my R Markdown I use `as.POSIXct()` to handle dates. Knitting from the Markdown GUI as well as using `rmarkdown::render()` both work fine on their own.

**Edit - Markdown YAML:**

Here is a snippet of the Markdown YAML used in the R Markdown document.

```r
---
output: 
  word_document: 
    reference_docx: word-styles-reference-01.docx
params:
  DateMin: 
    format: yyyy-mm-dd
    input: date
    label: "Date Start"
    startview: month
    value: yyyy-mm-dd
  DateMax: 
    format: yyyy-mm-dd
    input: date
    label: "Date End"
    startview: month
    value: yyyy-mm-dd
SiteName: 
    choices: ["Florida", "New York", "Washington"]        
    input: select
    label: "Site Name"
    value: Florida
---
```

**Sample In-Line Function Call:**

```r
render_reports(SiteName = "Florida", DateMin = "2016-01-01", DateMax = "2018-12-01")
```

Comment: please post your sample data

Comment: @Parfait I have added to the main post how the `DateMin` and `DateMax` params are called in the markdown YAML.

Comment: The example function call would be `render_reports(SiteName = "Florida", DateMin = "2016-01-01", DateMax = "2018-12-01")`

This breaks and produces the error above, but the individual lines with these  arguments runs as expected. @Parfait

Comment: No problem, and no I don't call it outside of this function. I have used this exact method for other functions in order to feed into `purrr::pmap()` for automated mass reporting, the only difference between this and my previous functions is the use of dates.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. It must be how you use `params$DateMin` and `params$DateMax` which need to be converted from string to date. See this [reproducible example](https://pastebin.com/RFHvawQM) that includes an Rmd at top and R `render` code at bottom. Change dates and HTML doc changes data and graphs.